# R - data frame to frequency table

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, subset

I have the following dataframe, `test`, in R:

```
   test <- data.frame(
        ID = c(1,1,2,2,2),
        Color = c("green","blue",rep("green",3)))

    > test
      ID Color
    1  1 green
    2  1  blue
    3  2 green
    4  2 green
    5  2 green
```

My desired output is a frequency table that shows the number of distinct colors per ID. E.g,

```
    > desired_output
    
       1    2 <NA> 
       1    1    0
```

I use the following dplyr code to produce this result:

```
    test_2 <- test %>% 
      group_by(ID) %>% 
      mutate(nDistColors = n_distinct(Color)) %>% 
      ungroup() %>% 
      as.data.frame() %>% 
      select(ID,nDistColors) %>% 
      distinct()

    desired_output <- table(test_2$nDistColors, useNA = "always")
```

I look at things like this a lot, so **I was wondering if there was a better way to write the code** to achieve this result. Particularly I feel like I remember **using a function that eliminated the need for the lines**:

```
      select(ID,nDistColors) %>% 
      distinct()
```

It would also be nice **if I didn't have to store the object test_2** but when I pipe straight into table, it changes the format to a 2 way frequency table which I don't prefer. **Can this be avoided?** I don't see a way in the pipe chain to specify what column I want frequencies for:

```
    test %>% 
     group_by(ID) %>% 
     mutate(nDistColors = n_distinct(Color)) %>% 
     ungroup() %>% 
     as.data.frame() %>% 
     select(ID,nDistColors) %>% 
     distinct() %>% 
      table(useNA = "always")
          nDistColors

    ID     1 2 <NA>
      1    0 1    0
      2    1 0    0
      <NA> 0 0    0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be made concise with `summarise` instead of `mutate` thus avoiding the step to do `distinct`.  Also, instead of storing the output to a temporary object, can `pull` the column 'n' and apply `table` on that

```
library(dplyr)
test %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    summarise(n = n_distinct(Color), .groups = 'drop') %>%
    pull(n) %>% 
    table(useNA = 'always')
# 1    2 <NA> 
# 1    1    0
```

Comment: Summarise! that's what it was. Thanks - I couldn't figure out what to google to find that without asking on here. I also didn't know about the pull method.

Comment: To summarise (no pun intended) - 1. "pull" is specifying what field "goes into" table? 2. What does ".groups = 'drop'" do?

Comment: @PrinceM 1. In your code `test_2$nDistColors` is extracting the column as a `vector`.  `pull` does the same thing on the 'n' summarised column.  2. `.groups = 'drop'` is not really needed here as there is only a single group variable and by default it does drop the last grouping column).  But using `.groups = 'drop'` avoids the surprises as well as removes those warning messages which could have some effect if you are writing it on RMD

Comment: Is it similar to “ungroup”?

Comment: @PrinceM you can do `ungroup` after those steps, but it will still may show that warning message from `summarise`